# RSYNC - owner/group local PC don't get set correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, permissions, rsync

When I run the following command owner:group are taken over correctly:

```
rsync -chavzP --delete SOURCE-SERVER DESTINATION-SAME-SERVER
```

However, when I run the same command to sync from the server to my local PC, the owner:group are not taken over:

```
rsync -chavzP --delete SOURCE-SERVER DESTINATION-MY-PC
```

I assume this is because on my PC these owner:group do not exist and instead they are replaced with root:root.

How can I still keep the owner:group from the server on my local PC so that in case of a restore the owner:group are set correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '--usermap=' and '--groupmap=' to match local user with remote or '--chown' options.
I think it will be something like this:

```
rsync -chavzP --chown="user:group"--delete SOURCE-SERVER DESTINATION-MY-PC


rsync -chavzP --usermap="localuser:remoteuser" --groupmap="localgroup:remotegroup" --delete SOURCE-SERVER DESTINATION-MY-PC
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not what I am looking for, as then the same user:group will still not be set as on the server.

Furthermore, on a server there are several user:groups on the file system.

Comment: You can use uid and gid to map. It will be the same user and group, yet the naming translation won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I don't used rsync with sudo (root-privileges) so that the parameters aren't get set correctly.

Now it works, adding --numeric-ids in the parameters ensure that always all is set correct on all systems.